# Running Serenity Project on Specific Nodes in Selenium Grid 4.7.2 Distributed Mode

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, serenity-bdd, selenium4, serenity

In Selenium Grid's distributed mode, with 50 registered nodes, is it possible to execute the Serenity project on only a specified set of 5 nodes in parallel?

I have initiated all components, including the Event bus, Session, Session queue, Distributor, and Router. While I can successfully register nodes, I am encountering issues when attempting to execute tasks on specific nodes.